# Different algorithms for longest increasing subsequence

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request

The [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem has a simple and elegant $O(n \log n)$ time solution via patience sorting.

Such a basic and well-studied problem, however, should have a number of different solutions, just as sorting does.

Are there other distinct $O(n \log n)$ time algorithms for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is a $O(n \log \log n)$ time algorithm to solve the longest increasing subsequence problem. You may find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patience_sorting#cite_note-Bespamyatnikh-3) and the paper by [Sergei Bespamyatnikh , Michael Segal](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.40.5912) helpful.